# convert list of latitude longitude to address gives only with 5 results

Tags: javascript, api, dictionary, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to get a list of address from a list of lat/long but i'm getting only the 5 first result. any help please to find all address?

```
for (let i = 0; i < result.mandats.length; i++) {

    var lat = result.mandats[i].lattitude;
    var long = result.mandats[i].longitude;
    console.log(lat, long)
    // here i get 92 results

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': latlng
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results[1].address_components[0])
            // and here i get only the first 5 address                                   
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking for help, please take the time to format your code consistently and readably. I've done it for you on this occasion. *(not my downvote!)*

Comment: What errors do you see in the web console and/or network tab? How are you checking to see if `status` is something other than `OK` (you don't have any code above for an `else` or similar on that check). The code is quite straightforward, sounds like you may be hitting some rate limit or similar with Geocoder.

Comment: Thank you T.J Crowder. That's my first question on Stackoverflow, I will format my code consistently next time.

Comment: `// and here i get only the first 5 address` - well then most likely the if condition wasn’t true for those entries ... have you checked yet what the `status` actually is …?

Comment: There is no error in the web console. how can I fix the problem of limit?

Comment: are you talking about **The Place Autocomplete service is a web service that returns place predictions**? @MohamedMaddouri

Comment: @CBroe, No, it's not from the if condition.